# How to install ubuntu alongside with windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I need to install ubuntu alongside with windows 7. But when I clicked on "Install ubuntu alongside with windows 7" there is a msg  "write previous changes to disk and continue". There was two options "Go back" and "Continue". I've three drives C:,D: and one is Recovery Drive. Will it affect the other drive when I click on continue?

Comment: Not sure why you are getting this message. Ordinarily it should not affect other partitions (don't call them drives, unless they are different hard drives). To be sure, make backups before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go with manual configuration of the partitions. Make an ext4 and a swap and install Ubuntu on the ext4 partition. GRUB will be installed on the MBR and it will prompt you to choose between Ubuntu or Windows.